# Generate Wordpress shortcode based on select menu choice

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields repeater field to generate a select menu with values that correspond with a Wordpress shortcode to display a form on the page. When a different option is select, a different form should appear. Here's the code I'm attempting:

```
<select id="forms">
    <option value="">Pick a form</option>
    <?php while(the_repeater_field('the_forms')): ?><option value="<?php the_sub_field('form_shorttag'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('form_name'); ?></option><?php endwhile; ?>
</select>

<div id="form_display"></div> 

<script>
      jQuery("#forms").on("change", function(){
        var theform = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery("#form_display").html(<?php echo do_shortcode(+ theform); ?>);
      })
</script>
```

I thought this would be a simple task but I'm definitely missing something because it's not working. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make variables in JavaScript with all the forms like:

```
var someform = <?php echo json_encode(do_shortcode("someform")); ?>;
```

The *json_encode* will wrap the PHP output in double quotes. Then make a switch in the onchange event:

```
var form_content;
switch (theform) {
    case "someform" :
        form_content = someform;
        break;
    (other cases)
}
jQuery("#form_display").html(form_content);
```

There are better ways, but this might do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is being setup so the client can add new forms on the fly in the CMS so the forms can't be hardcoded or pre-determined in the code. I feel like the biggest hurdle is properly handling this line of code: jQuery("#form_display").html(<?php echo do_shortcode(+ theform); ?>);